# Why isn't this google.load, google.setOnLoadCallback script working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this jquery work, according to firebug none of the javascript lines are being reached:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.4.0");
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
              $("p").css("background-color","red");
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
  <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing right parenthesis `)`:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.4.0");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $("p").css("background-color","red");
}); // <--- Here
```

Comment: +1 Looked at the wrong docs to start and thought the API key was required as well. Removed my answer since your was all that was needed :)